# Why ffmpeg shows 2 bitrates? How to change the second one?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I was comparing why my video plays poorly in my application. So I would like to compare with the video that works fine with `ffmpeg -i file`

The one that is working

```
  Duration: 00:02:19.96, start: 0.540000, bitrate: 1159 kb/s
    Stream #0:0[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg1video, yuv420p(tv), 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 1150 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 25 tbc
```

This one does not work fine

```
  Duration: 00:02:15.24, start: 0.533367, bitrate: 980 kb/s
    Stream #0:0[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg1video, yuv420p(tv), 256x256 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], 104857 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 29.97 tbc
```

I notice `104857 kb/s` in my video which probably cause the performance problem but what is it? I could not find information about how to read this output. Bitrate seems to be 980 kb/s, so what is this another kb/s? When I specify bitrate using `-vb` it seems to affect only the first one.